# Flutter | How to write a method to return List of String from a custom class model?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Class :

```
  class Cart {
      String id;
      Product product;
      String product_name;
      double quantity;
      List<Option> options;
      String userId;
    
      Cart();
    
      Map toMap() {
        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        map['product_name'] = product.name;
        map["id"] = id;
        map["quantity"] = quantity;
        map["product_id"] = product.id;
        map["price"] = product.price;
        map["user_id"] = userId;
        map["options"] = options.map((element) => element.id).toList();
        map["userphone"] = currentUser.value.phone;
        map["username"] = currentUser.value.name;
        return map;
      }
    }
```

In the code above, map is returned as a type Cart. I want to convert that as a type of List & return in the same way when called. How can this be achieved ?

**Expected output from the method as a dynamic value. This WHOLE value is going to be added to a List as an element at a specific position :**

```
[product_name: coke, id: 22, quantity: 1.0, product_id: 139, price: 20.0, user_id: 138, options: [], userphone: 9898565621, username: jamie]
```

Comment: Simply create function with return type `List`. Push all values in list and return it. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Ali, it'll be of terrific help if you could show a sample based on that example method. Been burning on this for few days now..

Comment: Can you show me the sample output you are expecting ?

Comment: @AdrianKarr so you want the values inside map such as id, quantity ... returned as a list ?

Comment: @Henok, yes. as a List of string or dynamic value . Ali : I've added the expected response from the method to the question..

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list like this while calling API

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
      EndPoint.Book,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var bookData = parsed['books'];
      List<Cart> cart= bookData.map<Cart>((e) => Cart.fromJson(e)).toList();
      print(data);
      return data;
    }
```

and use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ or https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable for making a data class.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample map with string values for testing and here is the code,

```
var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['product_name'] = 'product.name';
    map["id"] = 'id';
    map["quantity"] = 'quantity';
    map["product_id"] = 'product.id';
    map["price"] = 'product.price';
    map["user_id"] = 'userId';
    map["options"] = 'abc';
    map["userphone"] = 'currentUser.value.phone';
    map["username"] = 'currentUser.value.name';

    

    var keys = map.keys.toList();
    var values = map.values.toList();
    
    List result = List();
    int i = 0;
    values.map((value){
      result.add({keys[i] : values[i]});
      i++;
    }).toList();
  
    print(result);

    //you can return result here
```